# Pascal Triangle in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The code below generates a list of Pascal Coefficients. 
e.g `pascalList 3` outputs `[[1], [1,1], [1,2,1], [1,3,3,1]`
Can we write below sample in more idiomatic way

```
pascalList 0 = [[1]]
pascalList 1 = [[1], [1, 1]]
pascalList n = let pList = pascalList (n-1)
               in pList ++ [([1] ++ pascalCoeff (last pList) ++ [1])]
  where pascalCoeff (x:y:ys) = (x+y) : pascalCoeff (y:ys)
        pascalCoeff (x:[]) = []
```

Following code prints above list

```
listtoString :: [Int] -> String
listtoString [] = []
listtoString [x] = show x
listtoString (x:xs) = show x ++ " " ++ listtoString xs

pascalTriangle :: Int -> IO ()
pascalTriangle n = mapM_ putStrLn (((justify n) . map listtoString) (pascalList n))

justify :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
justify n (x:xs) = (concat (replicate n " ") ++ x) : justify (n-1) xs
justify _ [] = []
```

The sample output of the `pascalTriangle 4` will be

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is more idiomatic, but ever since I've seen an infinite list construction for the Fibonacci numbers, I've been in love with it, so here goes nothing.

```
pascalTriangle :: [[Integer]]
pascalTriangle = [1] : map newRow pascalTriangle
    where newRow y = 1 : zipWith (+) y (tail y) ++ [1]
```

To understand this, perhaps first you should look at simpler examples, e.g. an infinite list of zeros,

```
zeros = 0 : zeros
```

or the list of natural numbers,

```
nats = 0 : map (+1) nats
```

or my favourite, the list of fibonacci numbers,

```
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

---

That being said...

The line

```
pascalList 1 = [[1], [1, 1]]
```

is unnecessary, because you've already specified `pascalList 0`. The line

```
[([1] ++ pascalCoeff (last pList) ++ [1])]
```

is equivalent to

```
[[1] ++ pascalCoeff (last pList) ++ [1]]
```

which is equivalent to

```
[ 1 : pascalCoeff (last pList) ++ [1]]
```

Whenever possible, I try to use functions from the standard library instead of rolling my own using recursion, so for example instead of

```
pascalCoeff (x:y:ys) = (x+y) : pascalCoeff (y:ys)
pascalCoeff (x:[]) = []
```

I'd say that this function takes a list e.g. `[1,2,3,4]` and does the following:

```
  [1, 2, 3]
  [2, 3, 4]
+ ---------
  [3, 5, 7]
```

so it takes the `tail` (all but the first element) of the list, and the `init` (all but the last element) of the list, and adds them together element-wise.

There are built-in functions `tail`, and `init` that yield you these parts from a list, and luckily the function

```
zipWith (+)
```

does the adding part, so you can simply say

```
pascalCoeff y = zipWith (+) (init y) (tail y)
```

which is, due to the way `zipWith` works, the same as

```
pascalCoeff y = zipWith (+) y (tail y)
```

---

Similarly,

```
listtoString [] = []
listtoString [x] = show x
listtoString (x:xs) = show x ++ " " ++ listtoString xs
```

could simply be

```
listToString = unwords . map show
```

---

And

```
justify :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
justify n (x:xs) = (concat (replicate n " ") ++ x) : justify (n-1) xs
justify _ [] = []
```

could be

```
justify n ss = zipWith (++) padding ss
    where padding = [ replicate k ' ' | k <- [n, n-1 .. 1]]
```

or equivalently, after eta-reduction

```
justify n = zipWith (++) padding
    where padding = [ replicate k ' ' | k <- [n, n-1 .. 1]]
```

---

Due to the fact that lists are linked lists, appending to a list is expensive, while prepending to it is cheap. So if you do decide to construct a list element-by-element, then I'd say you should prepend the new elements, and perhaps after the list is built, use a `reverse`.

By the same logic, `head` is cheap, `last` is expensive.

Here's a possible implementation that uses what I've just said.

```
pascalList = reverse . pascalList'
pascalList' 0 = [[1]]
pascalList' n = new : old
    where new = 1 : pascalCoeff (head old) ++ [1]
          old = pascalList' (n-1)
```

---

In my opinion it is a good idea to

- separate pure and impure code,
- keep your code as modular as possible,
- write type signatures,
- use a linter like hlint,
- use functions from the standard library instead of writing explicit recursions.

Keeping this in mind, here's how I'd write the printing part.

```
listToString :: (Show a) => [a] -> String
listToString = unwords . map show

leftPadStrings :: [String] -> [String]
leftPadStrings ss = map leftPad ss
    where maxlen = maximum $ map length ss
          leftPad s = replicate (div (maxlen - length s) 2) ' ' ++ s 

paddedPascalTriangle :: Int -> [String]
paddedPascalTriangle n = leftPadStrings 
                       . map listToString 
                       . take n 
                       $ pascalTriangle

printPascalTriangle :: Int -> IO ()
printPascalTriangle = mapM_ putStrLn . paddedPascalTriangle
```

Running this, you should get something like the following:

```
*Main> printPascalTriangle 10
             1
            1 1
           1 2 1
          1 3 3 1
         1 4 6 4 1
       1 5 10 10 5 1
     1 6 15 20 15 6 1
    1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
  1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.

Comment: @Zeta "It is a good idea to separate pure and impure code" was the justification given for the rewrite.

Comment: @Zeta Your comment is justified, because initially I just wanted OP to know about infinite data types, because I think it's a cool concept. Since then I've added some of the more traditional code review.

Comment: If I had have time, I would have used the same concept :). That being  said, `zipWith func (init xs) (tail xs)` is the same as `zipWith func xs (tail xs)`, just as in `fibs = 1 : 1 : zibWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`.

Comment: @Zeta ah, yes, you are right, thanks. In fact I've used the same property when I rewrote `justify`. Oh well, I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 4):

The third case subsumes the second. All possible result lists are prefixes of the same infinite list - let's define that instead. `iterate` captures this pattern. A combination of `zipWith` and `tail` captures `pascalCoeff`.

```
pascalList :: [[Int]]
pascalList = flip iterate [1] $ \pList -> 1 : zipWith (+) pList (tail pList) ++ [1]
```